# highlight all possible closest distance between two lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

- I would like to highlight when the `x` line gets near to `y` line in all possible closest distance as highlighted in screenshot attached.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([2.524400911926705, 2.368138072935153, 2.205959061498106, 2.2005372256257942, 2.2055139955192544, 2.2305469178515978, 2.297332860786014, 2.246098680910791, 2.0989938541605397, 1.8250058120723907, 1.4188327783899695, 1.2192518229021516, 1.1351442159199223, 0.9980782079888968, 0.7604558005444915, 0.5161595462727746, 0.36035866846691533, 0.3849550329384783, 0.31049400757649437, 0.30046905599579077, 0.25967493089979143, 0.3268627254154808, 0.4403931886351984, 0.5410749682104097, 0.5148732289236477, 0.3720100630559955, 0.19042769591681008, 0.0930577194297939, -0.06565730738395814, -0.2275490542336911, -0.42279131681698345, -0.48000059585717736, -0.5273297962920651, -0.5336722775867884, -0.523784793956338, -0.603402465824729, -0.8024943458831331, -1.0873384758903057, -1.128201102239018, -1.174481494936913, -1.0282398482478357, -0.9809195854772952, -0.868051350138785, -0.7481910364105033, -0.8196601235302978, -0.7434645635981951, -0.6808787025278207, -0.7860222164752031, -0.9280460839100897, -1.03432636655657, -1.081875575279014, -1.1426975983489456, -1.0281541964995426, -0.7990600304181044, -0.5649941164748498, -0.5067943933971151, -0.31502202467925144, -0.1508126528954108, 0.05614127260923851, 0.2399810572911747, 0.3669212754061846, 0.5387756197936824, 0.7622082187319847, 0.9461259732423741, 1.1496384478788286, 1.2696594642135324, 1.4872296683024615, 1.7117393191606425, 1.8035148083611148, 1.9681421596337714, 2.1081990056777613, 2.386953526017919, 2.4513115858169385, 2.6205800191544313, 2.5980914125766503, 2.5955366192456495, 2.740252531943497, 2.8144287879666763, 2.629074814332853, 2.5041499083309873, 2.280415011510968, 2.0201051634438727, 1.7779808646627089, 1.6358267175871788, 1.4100839901908557, 1.1022789018867343, 1.062348660031489, 1.1043138704294506, 1.1716733501380077, 1.2461951835263108, 1.2520889825225368, 1.3533210018783848, 1.302339581124329, 1.3640226323155957, 1.4279165028237912, 1.4425579511953401, 1.2708661178546663, 1.1402144977973876, 0.9849721801138003, 0.8002669775968343, 0.546719973031145, 0.41682736292375466, 0.321477570242223, 0.34601573756879134, 0.4618104186642995, 0.5735947366887331, 0.6618178378568018, 0.7034533975997874, 0.5190544384514624, 0.41174409224174724, 0.23442978575553752, 0.14947493268789458, 0.05488665825964745, -0.04138491467710992, -0.034174495585602926, -0.00021562597737556644, -0.09246761558938488, -0.22910415883995938, -0.35907177353669795, -0.4097407391990373, -0.40647863834522013, -0.4248176916553348, -0.5843161785318216, -0.7265521306028404, -0.7762634647826872, -0.7433448409659604, -0.768911789930371, -0.7809780685785199, -0.749622838817686, -0.647112355799095, -0.42779944339656595, -0.31411782321333703, -0.21828045328959433, -0.12156136912392412, -0.0364217861549605, -0.08497143726310696, -0.05662747232190668, 0.0037175426299427272, 0.09562640001240652, 0.17691537488451559, 0.26570969565466385, 0.37293362565230836, 0.4909816206572941, 0.6313214273345693, 0.6543076413713607, 0.5467976080226435, 0.5265342188404247, 0.40653829604707425, 0.35256384604031155, 0.2488224524904581, 0.09769945238736, -0.007456168233488825, -0.13602588617595757, -0.12751468643079988, -0.1417293910585613, -0.07307447997152394, 0.0054793618199937555, -0.008023803292758203, -0.1301926784860825, -0.25314330516471273, -0.3553622485151209, -0.5031934748037656, -0.7720277008155563, -1.0990969354307936, -1.4433352595832503, -1.8513472199923626, -1.8523668787744327, -2.0769564475777997, -2.1399031872662135, -2.2430107105290062, -2.4545848588342096, -2.5748257458672015, -2.556725862535586, -2.484690616477792, -2.427059690176293, -2.2760718169751044, -2.230755713276494, -2.18418890025589, -2.1634976490259987, -2.00696179522447, -1.7960352796224015, -1.8177192314485637, -1.7485802281048564, -1.5939148525153541, -1.5861979359991665, -1.6378590648141653, -1.749013976964818, -1.718847438313901, -1.5719209771110059, -1.555361259905112, -1.637140840328982, -1.6913312142755217, -1.6203825760368318, -1.6643928158664494, -1.7572852508798178, -1.7246820560797005, -1.5039851706256968, -1.3713709706759118, -1.1313869568044765, -0.8754292598191, -0.6625230384223642, -0.5288498103944335, -0.5225947193708862, -0.48381828373288727, -0.40803824687992574, -0.44851783912469045, -0.6011611910073498, -0.6732189602486756, -0.7323728368878619, -0.8254150725808245, -0.8530075356157454, -0.8050756187842012, -0.6945298079471058, -0.5744779070582808, -0.46828934759201957, -0.48984202211170214, -0.581715575970577, -0.6430784392392752, -0.7037692473359698, -0.8605638206614685, -1.0310374741710007, -1.151254297015555, -1.3073073143779084, -1.4449863756803438, -1.7158746843853123, -1.8790393173093207, -1.8626122996023469, -2.002418911944744, -1.9359720251823092, -1.7549555523606273, -1.5692024120888277, -1.137752488376293, -0.6982090724946488, -0.3690145549521162, -0.06301868445638092, 0.21812359225060618, 0.5834843663971014, 0.9005791681768187, 1.4179545351760794, 1.6850952980936995, 1.9725121887204295, 2.173622149311427, 2.4811171651670065, 2.5031019534849293, 2.3872996998481426, 2.3315879660889323, 2.254188881621303, 2.1670620902962128, 2.149090249909932, 2.1097209704061015, 2.0492496434967507, 2.043931656391237, 1.9789795963353072, 1.9518065624300789, 1.9274196377189128, 1.746747037016803, 1.7623824975833031, 1.5942064909321516, 1.428322651066651, 1.463162119535923, 1.3501370635556214, 1.2150873807954667, 1.0316144113304517, 0.7755986727315758, 0.6204228242825138, 0.6353657028562338, 0.5887783205097321])

y = np.array([2.4579933760714425, 2.4400223154441845, 2.393209664654969, 2.354675176849134, 2.324842940583158, 2.305983736036846, 2.3042535609866794, 2.2926225849715016, 2.2538968388093092, 2.1681186334619253, 2.0182614624475343, 1.8584595345384578, 1.7137964708147506, 1.5706528182495798, 1.408613414708562, 1.2301226410214046, 1.0561698465105067, 0.921926883796101, 0.7996403085521797, 0.6998060580409019, 0.6117798326126798, 0.55479641117324, 0.5319157666656317, 0.5337476069745872, 0.5299727313643994, 0.4983801977027186, 0.43678969734553685, 0.36804330176238825, 0.281303179933119, 0.17953273309975698, 0.059067923116408905, -0.04874578067830834, -0.1444625838010597, -0.22230452255820543, -0.28260057683783196, -0.3467609546352114, -0.43790763288479573, -0.5677938014858978, -0.6798752616365218, -0.7787965082966, -0.8286851762868471, -0.8591320581249368, -0.8609159165277064, -0.8383709405042657, -0.8346287771094721, -0.8163959344072167, -0.7892924880313374, -0.7886384337201106, -0.8165199637581064, -0.8600812443177992, -0.9044401105100421, -0.9520916080778228, -0.9673041257621667, -0.9336553066933543, -0.8599230686496534, -0.7892973335991458, -0.6944422718151669, -0.5857163480312157, -0.4573448239031249, -0.317879647664265, -0.1809194630501751, -0.036980446481403584, 0.12285728656127409, 0.2875110238974941, 0.459936508693761, 0.6218810997977153, 0.7949508134986646, 0.9783085146310602, 1.143349773377071, 1.3083082506284112, 1.4682864016382813, 1.6520198265142088, 1.8118781783747546, 1.97361854653069, 2.098513119739882, 2.1979178196410354, 2.3063847621015277, 2.4079935672745574, 2.4522098166862163, 2.4625978350151705, 2.42616127031433, 2.3449500489402384, 2.2315562120847323, 2.1124103131852214, 1.9719450485863483, 1.7980118192464256, 1.6508791874034383, 1.5415661240086407, 1.4675875692345142, 1.4233090920928735, 1.389065070178806, 1.3819162565187217, 1.3660009214398432, 1.3656052636149938, 1.3780675114567533, 1.3909655994044707, 1.3669457030945098, 1.3215994620350853, 1.2542740056508284, 1.1634726000400295, 1.0401220746382527, 0.915463132295353, 0.7966660198847271, 0.7065359634215399, 0.6575908544700918, 0.6407916309138201, 0.6449968723024164, 0.6566881773618907, 0.629161429579805, 0.5856779621121935, 0.5154283268408623, 0.4422376480102687, 0.36476745006014444, 0.28353697711269354, 0.21999468257303423, 0.17595262086295227, 0.12226857357248483, 0.05199402708999598, -0.03021913303534282, -0.10612345426808172, -0.1661944910835094, -0.21791913119787448, -0.2911985406646639, -0.3782692586522992, -0.4578680998783768, -0.5149634480958936, -0.565753116462789, -0.6087981068859352, -0.6369630532722853, -0.6389929137776472, -0.5967542197014309, -0.5402269404038121, -0.4758376429809686, -0.4049823882095597, -0.33127026779863983, -0.28201050169153324, -0.23693389581760793, -0.1888036081280978, -0.13191760649999693, -0.07015101022309442, -0.0029788690475427565, 0.07220362989242747, 0.1559592280454008, 0.2510316679032345, 0.33168686259685976, 0.37470901168201654, 0.40507405311369815, 0.40536690170037337, 0.39480629056836103, 0.36560952295278043, 0.3120275088396963, 0.2481307734250593, 0.17129944150485593, 0.11153661591772476, 0.06088341452246754, 0.03409183562366924, 0.028369340862934144, 0.021090712031795675, -0.009165966071779968, -0.05796143389036652, -0.1174415968153174, -0.19459197241300707, -0.3100791180935169, -0.46788268156097224, -0.6629731971654278, -0.9006480017308147, -1.0909917771395383, -1.2881847112271907, -1.4585284064349953, -1.6154248672537974, -1.78325686556988, -1.9415706416293443, -2.064601685810593, -2.148619471944033, -2.204307515590485, -2.218660375867409, -2.2210794433492262, -2.213701334730559, -2.2036605975896473, -2.1643208371166116, -2.0906637256177696, -2.0360748267839286, -1.9785759070481141, -1.9016436961415621, -1.838554544113083, -1.7984154482532995, -1.7885351539956031, -1.7745976108592627, -1.7340622841096114, -1.6983220792687115, -1.6860858314807656, -1.6871349080397169, -1.6737844416391399, -1.6719061164846019, -1.688981943363645, -1.696121965906856, -1.6576946068506242, -1.6004298796156817, -1.5066212950534408, -1.3803828880065727, -1.236810918089731, -1.0952186965506716, -0.9806939011147146, -0.8813187776383491, -0.7866626714866645, -0.7190337050142697, -0.6954592022128857, -0.6910111538200436, -0.6992834904336073, -0.7245098068630507, -0.7502093526135896, -0.7611826058477119, -0.7478520462675907, -0.7131772184257288, -0.6641996442589869, -0.62932811982953, -0.6198056110577393, -0.6244601766940465, -0.6403219908224311, -0.6843703567902386, -0.7537037802663911, -0.8332138836162238, -0.9280325697685607, -1.0314233309509173, -1.1683136016377964, -1.3104587447721012, -1.4208894557381504, -1.5371953469794692, -1.6169506826200373, -1.6445516565681553, -1.6294818076722897, -1.5311359438130903, -1.364550569549402, -1.1654433666299449, -0.9449584301952321, -0.7123420257060644, -0.4531767472854312, -0.18242556419298123, 0.13765045568083095, 0.4471394241634047, 0.7522139770748096, 1.036495611522133, 1.3254199222511078, 1.560956328497872, 1.7262250027679262, 1.8472975954321273, 1.9286758526699626, 1.9763531001952126, 2.0109005301381564, 2.0306646181917456, 2.0343816232527465, 2.0362916298804445, 2.024829223171417, 2.0102246910231494, 1.993663680362302, 1.9442803516932021, 1.9079007808712223, 1.8451619228834082, 1.7617940685200568, 1.70206767872323, 1.6316815556897084, 1.5483627207108601, 1.4450130588347785, 1.3111301816141379, 1.1729887101478131, 1.0654641086894974, 0.9701269510535443])

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.plot(x,'g-',y,'r-')

plt.show()
```

- it's `MACD` and `SIGNAL` indicator data.
- when the green line is about to cross over the red line in `upward direction` *(when green is below red and green is about to be in crossover position to red)*, how do i detect the highlighted part on below attached image and mark that on the chart. I would like to mark all the closest distance where green line is about to cross over red in `upward direction` just before crossovers possible.

screenshot :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZWvf.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, but I have to admit that it is not very elegant. There are probably some machine learning or artificial intelligence solutions out there, but this is a rather simple mathematic approach. Additionally, it is a bit subjective with regard to which behaviour is considered as being approaching the other curve and which isn't.

In principle, the code calculates the difference between both curves at every point and the change in this difference (referred to as its slope). If the difference is negative (i.e. the green curve is below the red one in this implementation) and the slope of this difference is positive (i.e both curves approach each other), then mark this point as a possible sign for future crossover. To exclude false positives, it is possible to check the behaviour in the previous points, too, and only include those points that show the described trend over a "prolonged" (speaking of a few data points only) period.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([2.524400911926705, 2.368138072935153, 2.205959061498106, 2.2005372256257942, 2.2055139955192544, 2.2305469178515978, 2.297332860786014, 2.246098680910791, 2.0989938541605397, 1.8250058120723907, 1.4188327783899695, 1.2192518229021516, 1.1351442159199223, 0.9980782079888968, 0.7604558005444915, 0.5161595462727746, 0.36035866846691533, 0.3849550329384783, 0.31049400757649437, 0.30046905599579077, 0.25967493089979143, 0.3268627254154808, 0.4403931886351984, 0.5410749682104097, 0.5148732289236477, 0.3720100630559955, 0.19042769591681008, 0.0930577194297939, -0.06565730738395814, -0.2275490542336911, -0.42279131681698345, -0.48000059585717736, -0.5273297962920651, -0.5336722775867884, -0.523784793956338, -0.603402465824729, -0.8024943458831331, -1.0873384758903057, -1.128201102239018, -1.174481494936913, -1.0282398482478357, -0.9809195854772952, -0.868051350138785, -0.7481910364105033, -0.8196601235302978, -0.7434645635981951, -0.6808787025278207, -0.7860222164752031, -0.9280460839100897, -1.03432636655657, -1.081875575279014, -1.1426975983489456, -1.0281541964995426, -0.7990600304181044, -0.5649941164748498, -0.5067943933971151, -0.31502202467925144, -0.1508126528954108, 0.05614127260923851, 0.2399810572911747, 0.3669212754061846, 0.5387756197936824, 0.7622082187319847, 0.9461259732423741, 1.1496384478788286, 1.2696594642135324, 1.4872296683024615, 1.7117393191606425, 1.8035148083611148, 1.9681421596337714, 2.1081990056777613, 2.386953526017919, 2.4513115858169385, 2.6205800191544313, 2.5980914125766503, 2.5955366192456495, 2.740252531943497, 2.8144287879666763, 2.629074814332853, 2.5041499083309873, 2.280415011510968, 2.0201051634438727, 1.7779808646627089, 1.6358267175871788, 1.4100839901908557, 1.1022789018867343, 1.062348660031489, 1.1043138704294506, 1.1716733501380077, 1.2461951835263108, 1.2520889825225368, 1.3533210018783848, 1.302339581124329, 1.3640226323155957, 1.4279165028237912, 1.4425579511953401, 1.2708661178546663, 1.1402144977973876, 0.9849721801138003, 0.8002669775968343, 0.546719973031145, 0.41682736292375466, 0.321477570242223, 0.34601573756879134, 0.4618104186642995, 0.5735947366887331, 0.6618178378568018, 0.7034533975997874, 0.5190544384514624, 0.41174409224174724, 0.23442978575553752, 0.14947493268789458, 0.05488665825964745, -0.04138491467710992, -0.034174495585602926, -0.00021562597737556644, -0.09246761558938488, -0.22910415883995938, -0.35907177353669795, -0.4097407391990373, -0.40647863834522013, -0.4248176916553348, -0.5843161785318216, -0.7265521306028404, -0.7762634647826872, -0.7433448409659604, -0.768911789930371, -0.7809780685785199, -0.749622838817686, -0.647112355799095, -0.42779944339656595, -0.31411782321333703, -0.21828045328959433, -0.12156136912392412, -0.0364217861549605, -0.08497143726310696, -0.05662747232190668, 0.0037175426299427272, 0.09562640001240652, 0.17691537488451559, 0.26570969565466385, 0.37293362565230836, 0.4909816206572941, 0.6313214273345693, 0.6543076413713607, 0.5467976080226435, 0.5265342188404247, 0.40653829604707425, 0.35256384604031155, 0.2488224524904581, 0.09769945238736, -0.007456168233488825, -0.13602588617595757, -0.12751468643079988, -0.1417293910585613, -0.07307447997152394, 0.0054793618199937555, -0.008023803292758203, -0.1301926784860825, -0.25314330516471273, -0.3553622485151209, -0.5031934748037656, -0.7720277008155563, -1.0990969354307936, -1.4433352595832503, -1.8513472199923626, -1.8523668787744327, -2.0769564475777997, -2.1399031872662135, -2.2430107105290062, -2.4545848588342096, -2.5748257458672015, -2.556725862535586, -2.484690616477792, -2.427059690176293, -2.2760718169751044, -2.230755713276494, -2.18418890025589, -2.1634976490259987, -2.00696179522447, -1.7960352796224015, -1.8177192314485637, -1.7485802281048564, -1.5939148525153541, -1.5861979359991665, -1.6378590648141653, -1.749013976964818, -1.718847438313901, -1.5719209771110059, -1.555361259905112, -1.637140840328982, -1.6913312142755217, -1.6203825760368318, -1.6643928158664494, -1.7572852508798178, -1.7246820560797005, -1.5039851706256968, -1.3713709706759118, -1.1313869568044765, -0.8754292598191, -0.6625230384223642, -0.5288498103944335, -0.5225947193708862, -0.48381828373288727, -0.40803824687992574, -0.44851783912469045, -0.6011611910073498, -0.6732189602486756, -0.7323728368878619, -0.8254150725808245, -0.8530075356157454, -0.8050756187842012, -0.6945298079471058, -0.5744779070582808, -0.46828934759201957, -0.48984202211170214, -0.581715575970577, -0.6430784392392752, -0.7037692473359698, -0.8605638206614685, -1.0310374741710007, -1.151254297015555, -1.3073073143779084, -1.4449863756803438, -1.7158746843853123, -1.8790393173093207, -1.8626122996023469, -2.002418911944744, -1.9359720251823092, -1.7549555523606273, -1.5692024120888277, -1.137752488376293, -0.6982090724946488, -0.3690145549521162, -0.06301868445638092, 0.21812359225060618, 0.5834843663971014, 0.9005791681768187, 1.4179545351760794, 1.6850952980936995, 1.9725121887204295, 2.173622149311427, 2.4811171651670065, 2.5031019534849293, 2.3872996998481426, 2.3315879660889323, 2.254188881621303, 2.1670620902962128, 2.149090249909932, 2.1097209704061015, 2.0492496434967507, 2.043931656391237, 1.9789795963353072, 1.9518065624300789, 1.9274196377189128, 1.746747037016803, 1.7623824975833031, 1.5942064909321516, 1.428322651066651, 1.463162119535923, 1.3501370635556214, 1.2150873807954667, 1.0316144113304517, 0.7755986727315758, 0.6204228242825138, 0.6353657028562338, 0.5887783205097321])

y = np.array([2.4579933760714425, 2.4400223154441845, 2.393209664654969, 2.354675176849134, 2.324842940583158, 2.305983736036846, 2.3042535609866794, 2.2926225849715016, 2.2538968388093092, 2.1681186334619253, 2.0182614624475343, 1.8584595345384578, 1.7137964708147506, 1.5706528182495798, 1.408613414708562, 1.2301226410214046, 1.0561698465105067, 0.921926883796101, 0.7996403085521797, 0.6998060580409019, 0.6117798326126798, 0.55479641117324, 0.5319157666656317, 0.5337476069745872, 0.5299727313643994, 0.4983801977027186, 0.43678969734553685, 0.36804330176238825, 0.281303179933119, 0.17953273309975698, 0.059067923116408905, -0.04874578067830834, -0.1444625838010597, -0.22230452255820543, -0.28260057683783196, -0.3467609546352114, -0.43790763288479573, -0.5677938014858978, -0.6798752616365218, -0.7787965082966, -0.8286851762868471, -0.8591320581249368, -0.8609159165277064, -0.8383709405042657, -0.8346287771094721, -0.8163959344072167, -0.7892924880313374, -0.7886384337201106, -0.8165199637581064, -0.8600812443177992, -0.9044401105100421, -0.9520916080778228, -0.9673041257621667, -0.9336553066933543, -0.8599230686496534, -0.7892973335991458, -0.6944422718151669, -0.5857163480312157, -0.4573448239031249, -0.317879647664265, -0.1809194630501751, -0.036980446481403584, 0.12285728656127409, 0.2875110238974941, 0.459936508693761, 0.6218810997977153, 0.7949508134986646, 0.9783085146310602, 1.143349773377071, 1.3083082506284112, 1.4682864016382813, 1.6520198265142088, 1.8118781783747546, 1.97361854653069, 2.098513119739882, 2.1979178196410354, 2.3063847621015277, 2.4079935672745574, 2.4522098166862163, 2.4625978350151705, 2.42616127031433, 2.3449500489402384, 2.2315562120847323, 2.1124103131852214, 1.9719450485863483, 1.7980118192464256, 1.6508791874034383, 1.5415661240086407, 1.4675875692345142, 1.4233090920928735, 1.389065070178806, 1.3819162565187217, 1.3660009214398432, 1.3656052636149938, 1.3780675114567533, 1.3909655994044707, 1.3669457030945098, 1.3215994620350853, 1.2542740056508284, 1.1634726000400295, 1.0401220746382527, 0.915463132295353, 0.7966660198847271, 0.7065359634215399, 0.6575908544700918, 0.6407916309138201, 0.6449968723024164, 0.6566881773618907, 0.629161429579805, 0.5856779621121935, 0.5154283268408623, 0.4422376480102687, 0.36476745006014444, 0.28353697711269354, 0.21999468257303423, 0.17595262086295227, 0.12226857357248483, 0.05199402708999598, -0.03021913303534282, -0.10612345426808172, -0.1661944910835094, -0.21791913119787448, -0.2911985406646639, -0.3782692586522992, -0.4578680998783768, -0.5149634480958936, -0.565753116462789, -0.6087981068859352, -0.6369630532722853, -0.6389929137776472, -0.5967542197014309, -0.5402269404038121, -0.4758376429809686, -0.4049823882095597, -0.33127026779863983, -0.28201050169153324, -0.23693389581760793, -0.1888036081280978, -0.13191760649999693, -0.07015101022309442, -0.0029788690475427565, 0.07220362989242747, 0.1559592280454008, 0.2510316679032345, 0.33168686259685976, 0.37470901168201654, 0.40507405311369815, 0.40536690170037337, 0.39480629056836103, 0.36560952295278043, 0.3120275088396963, 0.2481307734250593, 0.17129944150485593, 0.11153661591772476, 0.06088341452246754, 0.03409183562366924, 0.028369340862934144, 0.021090712031795675, -0.009165966071779968, -0.05796143389036652, -0.1174415968153174, -0.19459197241300707, -0.3100791180935169, -0.46788268156097224, -0.6629731971654278, -0.9006480017308147, -1.0909917771395383, -1.2881847112271907, -1.4585284064349953, -1.6154248672537974, -1.78325686556988, -1.9415706416293443, -2.064601685810593, -2.148619471944033, -2.204307515590485, -2.218660375867409, -2.2210794433492262, -2.213701334730559, -2.2036605975896473, -2.1643208371166116, -2.0906637256177696, -2.0360748267839286, -1.9785759070481141, -1.9016436961415621, -1.838554544113083, -1.7984154482532995, -1.7885351539956031, -1.7745976108592627, -1.7340622841096114, -1.6983220792687115, -1.6860858314807656, -1.6871349080397169, -1.6737844416391399, -1.6719061164846019, -1.688981943363645, -1.696121965906856, -1.6576946068506242, -1.6004298796156817, -1.5066212950534408, -1.3803828880065727, -1.236810918089731, -1.0952186965506716, -0.9806939011147146, -0.8813187776383491, -0.7866626714866645, -0.7190337050142697, -0.6954592022128857, -0.6910111538200436, -0.6992834904336073, -0.7245098068630507, -0.7502093526135896, -0.7611826058477119, -0.7478520462675907, -0.7131772184257288, -0.6641996442589869, -0.62932811982953, -0.6198056110577393, -0.6244601766940465, -0.6403219908224311, -0.6843703567902386, -0.7537037802663911, -0.8332138836162238, -0.9280325697685607, -1.0314233309509173, -1.1683136016377964, -1.3104587447721012, -1.4208894557381504, -1.5371953469794692, -1.6169506826200373, -1.6445516565681553, -1.6294818076722897, -1.5311359438130903, -1.364550569549402, -1.1654433666299449, -0.9449584301952321, -0.7123420257060644, -0.4531767472854312, -0.18242556419298123, 0.13765045568083095, 0.4471394241634047, 0.7522139770748096, 1.036495611522133, 1.3254199222511078, 1.560956328497872, 1.7262250027679262, 1.8472975954321273, 1.9286758526699626, 1.9763531001952126, 2.0109005301381564, 2.0306646181917456, 2.0343816232527465, 2.0362916298804445, 2.024829223171417, 2.0102246910231494, 1.993663680362302, 1.9442803516932021, 1.9079007808712223, 1.8451619228834082, 1.7617940685200568, 1.70206767872323, 1.6316815556897084, 1.5483627207108601, 1.4450130588347785, 1.3111301816141379, 1.1729887101478131, 1.0654641086894974, 0.9701269510535443])

#difference between both curves to see which one is below
difference = x-y 

slope = [0] #start with 0, so the slope at index i depicts the change between i and i-1
for i in range(len(difference)-1):
    #"slope" here is the change in y between two adjacent points
    slope.append(difference[i+1]-difference[i])
slope = np.array(slope)

cutoff = 3
target_points = []

for i in range(cutoff, len(difference)-1):
    #consider the last (cutoff + 1) elements, including element i (hence i+1 when slicing)
    if np.all(difference[i-cutoff:i+1] < 0) and np.all(slope[i-cutoff:i+1] > 0):
        target_points.append(i)
    #alternative:
    #if difference[i] < 0 and slope[i]>0:
    #    target_points.append(i)
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(x,'g-',y,'r-')

for i, point in enumerate(target_points):
    ax.plot(point,x[point],'bo',fillstyle='none',markersize=15)
plt.show()
```

[image: Result when considering 3 consecutive points]

This is definitely not a perfect solution, but I think it comes close to what you wanted to see. You could play around with the `cutoff` variable and even the if statement to determine segments that are approaching each other. To clean it up, you could plot only the last or first or center point of a series of consecutive points, but I left this out because either way had its pros and cons.